# Copy Paste Removes Spaces

Tags: lineageos, bugs, copy-paste, debug

Every time I copy and paste text on my android phone white spaces are removed, i.e.:

Copy:

`this is a test`

Paste:

`thisisatest`

The behaviour is the same no matter which app I copy/paste text from/into.
I'm using LineageOS and this started happening about 2 weeks ago, but I cannot precise the exact date or which apps were installed right before it.

Any idea how to fix/debug this?

Comment: I'm having this issue, too. If I restart the phone, it starts working again for a while.

Comment: It was an app that I had installed, once removed the problem.disappeared, but the issue is that I cannot recall which app it was... If I remember later, I'll post it as an answer. Try removing opera browser or any remote desktop app (teamviewer, anydesk) if you've them installed and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Some Apps - MBWay included - allow the user to copy a content automatically removing the white spaces. In fact what happens is that 2 entries are stored within clipboard. The original entry preserves the white spaces. The second entry records all content without white spaces. Very useful when you are copying Credit Card numbers. Some of those Apps don't revert back that 'configuration'. The quick solution is to force stop that specific App. Look for apps that have embed COPY features.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you have mbway installed?

I can confirm it's mbway. If you force stop the app, copy paste starts working fine again

Comment: I do have mb way installed, but that stopped happening and I still have mbway.